# Как в CMAKE добавить параметр -fvisibility=default?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, webkit

Пытаюсь собрать qtwebkit из исходников и получить доступ к WebCore. Т.к. qt прячет API WebCore за своим, нужно как то экспортировать. 
В статье на хабре [тут ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/237771/)

> С shared бибилиотекой есть другая проблема: qt — не экспортирует API webkita, а прячет его за своим. Лечится это "-fvisibility=default" вместо hidden.

Описывается как собрать, но без деталей, предполагается что читатель хоть как то знаком со сборкой и плюсами. Проблема в том, что я в этом полный 0.

Вообщем такой вопрос, как экспортировать приватный API к WebCore qtwebkit ?

Comment: Попробуйте `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}"-fvisibility=default")`

Comment: Это в каком фале make нужно прописать ?

Comment: cmake очевидно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно будет установить переменную `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` во время конфигурации из командной строки:

`cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fvisibility=default" .`

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что _переписывание_ внутренней переменной CMake это хорошая идея? Это очевидно не верный подход. Поэтому пока что ловите -1.

Comment: В каком она месте внутренняя? Это каноничный способ добавить свои флаги компиляции к проекту.

Comment: Каноничный он почему? Кто этот канон принял? Это абсолютно неверный метод добавления флагов компиляции к проекту. А внутренняя она потому, что её выставляет CMake и то, что Вы выставляете в командной строке абсолютно фиолетово. Любой может перезаписать её в файле проекта.

Comment: Если уж и использовать эту переменную то только так, как в комментариях это указал ishidex, но это тоже не лучший способ. По уму это всё делается через `add_compile_options` и `target_compile_options`

Comment: @ixSci вообще, ИМХО, подход с переписыванием данное переменной в cmake может быть по двум причинам: либо в проекте есть подпроект у которого нужны какие-то отдельные флаги, которые никогда не меняются, либо криворукасть. Добавлять флаг компиляции так, как описано выше - вполне нормально, если флаг должен быть применен ко всем файлам в проекте (или по возможности ко всем) и он не обязателен, а опционален.

Comment: @ixSci, указать `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` в командной строке — это как раз абсолютно правильный способ задать свои флаги на этапе конфигурации перед сборкой... «неверный метод» — это как раз править какие-либо файлы проекта без необходимости.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, если нужно собирать чужой проект с модифицированными флагами компиляции, то нужно использовать внешнюю `CXXFLAGS`, а не выставлять `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` в консоли. Работа с `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` это всегда неверно. Это внутренняя переменная, которую вообще не нужно трогать. Но это относится только к сборке чужого проекта, во всех остальных случаях должны быть исправлены проектные файлы.

Comment: @ixSci, значение `CXXFLAGS` из `env` просто используется для инициализации `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` при первой конфигурации, так что совет использовать одно вместо другого звучит довольно бессмысленно...  И она нисколько не является «*внутренней*» (`INTERNAL`), в том смысле как это задаётся `set( ... CACHE INTERNAL)`; это обычное строковое значение вполне доступное для модификации пользователем, как в проекте, так и в командной строке, но помеченное как *продвинутое* (см. [`mark_as_advanced()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/mark_as_advanced.html)).

Comment: @Fat-Zer, если Вы выставите `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` значит значение `CXXFLAGS` будет проигнорировано, т.е. Вы просто переписывает переменную. Это не нормально, нормально использовать средства так, чтобы добавлять, а не перезаписывать. В текущем CMake нет вообще ни одного случая, в котором имеет смысл использовать `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. По крайней мере мне такие случая не известны и ни разу не встречал ни в практике, ни в вопросах.

Comment: @ixSci, самое простое — изменить флаги в уже сконфигурированном проекте без необходимости удалять/пересоздавать всё дерево сборки и указывать все остальные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_definitions(-fvisibility=default)
```